# Allow Developer to see Jira Service Desk Ticket

Tags: jira

I would like the developer to have read only access to the Jira Service Desk ticket that originated the Developer ticket.

Right now I create the developer ticket with `.../Create Linked Issue`.  That creates a developer ticket.  When I look at the developer ticket I can see the link to the Service Desk ticket.  But when the developer look at same ticket he does not see the service desk ticket.

I have tried adding him as a "Participant" on the SD ticket.

As a patch I have added the developer as a user in the organization related to the SD ticket so he can see the ticket as tho he were the client.  This is sufficient until we can figure out how to get him access.

Jira server seems to have a feature called "Collaborator".  That seems ideal, but it does not seem to be available to Jira cloud.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may know, JIRA Service Desk is licensed "per agent" and not per user.

What's the difference between an agent and a JIRA user? JIRA Service Desk agents work on requests and respond to customers.

In JIRA Service Desk, customers do not consume user license seats. If you have a JIRA Service Desk project, there is no limit as to the number of customers that could create an issue in that system. Hence Atlassian doesn't have to "assign you a Service Desk license" as you put it in order for you to create a ticket on the https://support.atlassian.com site (SAC as it is called).

So if you have collaborators who will not interact with your customers/clients, you can purchase Jira Software (or Jira Core) instead for only USD $10 per month (1-10 users). These developers need not to have that "agent functionality specifically" when they can take the role of a '[Collaborator](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/SERVICEDESK025/Collaborator)' for Server, hence they will not be counted towards your agent seat.

For cloud, you can [check it here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/servicedeskcloud/setting-up-service-desk-users-732528877.html#Settingupservicedeskusers-limitedInvolveJiraSoftwareorJiraCoreusers).

Collaborators can:

- View issues, comments and attachments
- Add attachments and delete their own attachments
- Add internal comments to issues and delete their own comments
- Watch and vote for issues

These developers can take advantage of these features within their Jira Software/Core seat.